# The referenced component 'EntityFramework' could not be found.

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

So im downloading a project at home from work over team foundation server. I download the project and it won't compile because of the error. Warning    2   The referenced component 'EntityFramework' could not be found. Could anyone offer guidance in how I can get entity framework to work. I installed nuget package.

Thankyou

Comment: In all projects that use the data objects?

Comment: What do you mean? All the elements that use the database give me compiler errors. does something have to be changed?

Comment: Did you restore the packages with Nuget?  They are usually not stored in source control.  Have you made sure that all projects in your solution that reference your data object have an active reference to the Entity Framework?  These are the common problems with this sort of error.

Comment: How do i make sure its an active reference?

Comment: The packages according to Nuget manager are installed

Comment: Expand out your references node in your projects.  Is there any sort of trouble icon on the reference?

Comment: Entityframework  has a trouble icon thats it

Comment: Then Nuget has not downloaded the libraries.  I can't walk you through that, but if you play with the Nuget app, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: I deleted it and reinstalled it and nothing worked. I'm just confused in what to do I thought it would work as it did at work

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suggest you to check:

1) **"Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build"** ticked

`Tool --> Options... --> Package Manager --> General`
[image]

2) **"Project selected"** ticked

`Solution Explorer --> right-click on the solution/project --> Manage NuPackages`
[image]

3) **Rebuild Solution**

[image]

**EDIT**

For completeness I would like to add that if you are working with a CI system (e.g. Jenkins) or you are using MSBuild on the command line, you need to select *Enable NuGet Package Restore* to make it work:

[Enable NuGet Package Restore http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Workflows/images/enable-package-restore.png](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Workflows/images/enable-package-restore.png)

Comment: Unfortunately there are many cases where "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" is enabled, but NuGet still doesn't actually download and restore the references. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. The user-experience with NuGet is still far from perfect.

Comment: @Dai: Sometimes, it is necessary to delete the content of the _packages_ folder. If you do that, the package restore always works without fail.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem. I solved it like this:

1. Choose `References` > Right-click > `Add Reference ...`
2. Choose `Browse` tab
3. Find your *Project Folder* > `packages` > `EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0` > `lib`
4. Choose `EntityFramework.dll`
5. Click `OK`

Comment: Obviously the details are now different (EntityFramework has had quite a few revisions since this answer), but this was the best solution when NuGet already had the package installed but the project had the wrong path for the dll.

Comment: This was a useful answer. I recently upgraded the version of one package using NuGet but the reference in the csproj file was not updated to the more recent DLL.

Comment: This worked for me.  Using TFS 2015 and VS 2015, I branched the main code line and this reference was broken in the branched version.

Comment: Yeah, this finally worked for me, and now I recall I used that trick in a completely different scenario. Always a good way to try if you want to avoid pulling in a whole hierarchy of packages once _again_ in another project when all that Visual Studio really wants is a specific library due to (in this case) the class `DbContext` being inherited from.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me, after I **moved projects** to a subfolder.
Then, the relative paths to the packages folder were not correct anymore.

Got errors like that:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.1\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets. PROJECTNAME D:\VSTS\TEAMPROJECT\src\PROJECTFOLDER\PROJECTNAME.csproj

[image]

Fixed it by editing the *.csproj file and corrected the relative paths, in my case from `..\packages` to `..\..\packages`

Also make sure to check the paths under

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are good ways suggested by the developers, you may also try this solution to solve your problem.

In your case your project has a reference to the EntityFramework library, but library it self is not available to you project. You may try either the following:

- If you have NuGet package manager:

> Click on **Project-> Manage NuGet Packages**. It will open following window.
>
> Find the EntityFramework and click Install.

[image: NuGet Package Window]

---

- Alternatively, Download the EntityFramework library to your computer, then

> **Right-Click the Prject-> Add References...-> Browse-> Locate your
>   EntityFramework library-> Click OK**

[image: Like this image]

---

- Optionally you may use package manager to install library reference, 
check this link [package-manager-console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) (Note: This might require NuGet Package manager)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding Entity Framework reference (Add ref) under C:\ Prog Files\Entity...\Binaries\Entity Framework.dll into my project. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, but for anyone that this may help..

What worked for me was to go to the 'Packages' folder in the root of my solution and delete the EntityFramework.6.4.4 folder.

Then, go to `Manage Nuget Packages` menu option, and this banner pops up:

[image]

After pressing `Restore` the missing reference was restored.