# Namespace cannot be found when rebuilding entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I've rebuilt my entity framework in an MVC 3 project.  This was working before I did this.  Now though, I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'myEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

everywhere in my code where it references the Entity Framework.  This was working before the rebuild so it follows that it has to be that.  I've checked that the name of the connection in my web.config and have deleted and re-installed the entity framework but it's not being referenced.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: were your Entity Framework classes built using a T4 template? the rebuild could have caused the templates to wipe their code gen, you might have to run the templates again.

Comment: you aren't receiving an error that Entity Framework couldn't be found, but that your `myEntities` class couldn't be found.  This tells me that whatever code file held the 'myEntities' class was wiped by the rebuild... what method did you use to set up Entity Framework (Code First, Model First, Database First)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo and behold, it was simple.  I named the connection string to a different name than the object name I call in my code!

Comment: Mine was the same, in the Model.Context.cs, it updated the name of my Entities to Dev and I had to change it back to what I was using in every reference in my code.

Answer (score 5):

Today I faced the same issue and waste my entire day.

Finally I start reading errors line by line and found the exact error.

1. On two tables I removed relationship and that was all the cause of problem.
2. Even I added all the relationship and update model but still not working.
3. Removed those tables from emdx on which I removed and re-added relationship
4. rebuild and found everything gone except the removed tables
5. Added those tables and done

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by deleting all tables from Entity .edmx then right click and select update model from database and select all tables you want ,Next rebuild the project.

Comment: Had the same problem after adding a new table to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check out this other SO post which has a very similar problem to yours. It gives a few different suggestions to fix your problem and hopefully one of them will work out for you! Cheers!

[The referenced component 'EntityFramework' could not be found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950638/the-referenced-component-entityframework-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Yes, I've seen this post.  It doesn't help much.  I think it's something I did wrong while setting it up.

Comment: To clarify, I didn't use NuGet or need to add the EF's dll in the Reference before and it was fine.  It may solve the problem but I don't want to go down a longer root if the answer's more simple than that.

Answer (score 0):

Today I updated one table column.  Had to delete and then re-add the table and any tables with a relationship to it to get it to generate properly again.

Answer (score 0):

you can make another connection string...

or

try mentioning Using system.data.entity,

or

intall entity framework using manage Nuget Packages

or

select project name-> click tools(from menu items)-> package manager(nuget)->terminal
paste and run=> install-package EntityFramework

or

[Find entity name in model browser as for example(green name in red circle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZvYE.png)