# Reference to assembly error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I've implemented the RoleProvider class, there I created Domain class object which is in another assembly, my assembly has a reference to that one.

> Error 3   The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an
>   assembly  that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. D:\Visual Studio 2013\Group
>   06\G06_Store\Store.Facade\StoreRoleProvider.cs    17  24  Store.Facade

How can I fix this error?

Comment: By adding the reference of EntityFramework in your project.

Comment: I've got nuget package in my project

Comment: here is your solution :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064449/the-type-system-data-entity-dbcontext-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-re

Answer (score 8):

open visual studio and go to tools bar open Nuget package manager and open nuget package manager console and install Entity framework just paste this into the console window:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Answer (score 6):

1) Uninstall Entity Framework from **All** projects

2) Restart Visual Studio

3) Reinstalling Entity Framework to all required projects

and **it started working**

Comment: If you have a Repository and Web project, try installing it to both, not just the Repository

Answer (score 0):

I've also found that if you have say a Console App as the main project, with a unit test project running on the side, this error will come up if you don't have a reference to EntityFramework on the unit test project you will get this error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console
Then select the project name from Default Project in which you facing the above- 
mentioned error. Then simply install the below mentioned package :

install-package entityframework -version 6.0.0.0