# Entity Framework throws an error in my .net namespace

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Error:

> The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

As you can see my Entity Framework is complaining at the reference, tried to solve it but got nowhere. Has someone experienced this problem before? I'm basically trying to do this: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: What did you tried to do to resolve?
Added the dll manually?
installed the nuget package on the project?

Comment: You may want to try the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188454/reference-to-assembly-error

Comment: You need to install EF first from NuGet before it will work with your project.

Comment: Try restore packages if you downloaded the files from web.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your solution and follow this steps(provided that you use a downloaded zip from the page you specified):

- Right click on sln node and `Enable Nuget package restore`, then rebuild you sln.
- If not already installed try open the Manage Nuget Package and check EF is installed.
- Would not recommend loading dll by hand, but you can try adding it.