# Error building Repository in a seprate project(library) within the same solution

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

So, I was following this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

to learn and implement Repository pattern in my solution which consisted of a single project.

But my senior told me this is not the way we usually use and the repository is referenced from a different way(not withing the project). Using a class library, adding it to the solution and then referencing it.

When I tried doing it that way I am getting error.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki5wh.png)

I had shifted my repository interface, class and UnitOfwork class to the library class within the same solution(As a different project)

I have even tried adding references to assembly using nuget 
as shown in this question 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624575/entity-framework-throws-an-error-in-my-net-namespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And where is Your dbContext?
Check namespace of StudentsDemoEntities, and check if repository project referenced project with context. 
Then add using statment for dbContext.

**Edit**
Your repository can't "see" dbContext.
Move Your context to repository project and this error will be resolved. 
Remember about namespace!

Comment: dbContext is in my .Net Web application project (made using database first way)

Comment: if I try adding reference of project in my library, it gives error saying "it will cause circular dependency"

Comment: Then Your repository can't "see" context.
You need to move context to different project (it can be in repository project).