# ERROR: EntityFramework.dll not found after I installed Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, edmx, ado.net-entity-data-model

How can I resolve this error? I have added the Entity Framework 6.1.3 from this link: [Download EntityFramework 6.1.3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) for Visual Studio 2013 (after uninstalling and re-installing it again and again)

Now that it has been added and in the project created a `.emdx` file using `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`. When I try to build it, the following error pops:

```
EntityFramework.dll not found (after Compilation)
```

Comment: Can any one please, tell me where EntityFramework 6.1.3 is installed as i have searched the **.DLL** path in VS-2013 and unable to find it.

Comment: That link is for the tools, not EF. Install Entity Framework with Nuget.https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework

Comment: It is already installed in Nuget @SteveGreene and its version is 6.1.3

Comment: OK, then you are probably experiencing a Nuget issue. Lot's of those on SO with solutions such as restoring Nuget packages, remove and reinstall, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950638/the-referenced-component-entityframework-could-not-be-found

Comment: Thanks. Now i am in the middle of uninstalling visual studio-2013 and will re install it and then firstly i'll check the updates. Thanks @SteveGreene

Comment: install EF via NuGet to the project https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.1.3

Comment: Yes i have un installed VS-2013. But the Windows **C://** directory still contains Micosoft Visual Studio 11.0, Micosoft Visual Studio 12.0, Micosoft Visual Studio 13.0 folders. Can i simply delete them. Would it not create a problem in future ?? @magicandre1981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't uninstall the Visual Studio. Installing the [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762), only makes it possible to use [EF features in the VS IDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj650889.aspx).

To use EF in your application [install the NuGet Package](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console#installing-a-package) for EF:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

The `EntityFramework.dll` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` are added to your solution.

Comment: Yes @magnicandre1981 ,  this is the solution you/i found, but now i have uninstalled VS-2013. Working fine after Installing VS-2013 again. The main reason for the problem was that i uninstalled the EFTools.msi manually from the Window Explorer by double clicking it. Uninstalled, installed, uninstalled, installed and i think after that the path got last by Visual Studio 2013 as it is not a good sign from Microsofts Product. Thanks for the solution, this is my solution.

Comment: I installed the package both through the package manager and the GUI and still no entityframework.dll. This is very frustrating.