# Entity Data Model Wizard not showing EF Designer - DLL Not found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model, entity-framework-designer

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application) to create `.edmx` file using a Database First Approach (using `Add->NewItem-> ADO.NET Entity Data Model`)

When I enter into the Entity Data Model Wizard, I don't see any option like `EF Designer from database`.

To resolve this, I installed EFTools from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762), but after installing it I see things working fine till the `.edmx` is generated. The following problem arose when i try to build the project.

### Problem

After compiling/building, I see this error:

```
EntityFramework.dll could not be found
```

Comment: Did you add reference to EF in your project?

Comment: Any chance you have VS installed to a non-default location, for instance somewhere on D: drive?  If so, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664833/metadata-file-not-found-data-entity-model

Comment: I've searched the location C:/......Common7/IDE/, their is no such file named as EntityFramework.dll . kindly guide what to do now  ?@DavidTansey ?

Comment: @Turo thanks, but i don't have a EntityFramework.dll file in the installation location (given in above comment), so first i'll have to add it but how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i uninstalled the `Entity-Framework Tool`, following the `Stack-Overflow Question/Answers` mentioned below:

[☒ Don't follow this link if you want to add EFTools ☒](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046081/missing-ado-net-entity-data-model-on-visual-studio-2013)

Now, that i installed EFTools using `EFTools.msi` after uninstalling ( using `EFTools.msi` ), its path changes from the original one so follow this solution:

[☑ Follow the Accepted Answer of this Link ☑](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308031/error-entityframework-dll-not-found-after-i-installed-entity-framework-6-1-3?noredirect=1#comment56374977_34308031)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and ran Entity Framework tools for visual studio 2013 and it appeared.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: Thanks, that is also a quicker solution @KumaranPC.